# Ember.js removeObject in forEach not removing all Objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to iterate over an array in Ember and remove objects from the array with `removeObject()`. The example below only removes some objects from the array. I would expect it to iterate over all objects and then remove them:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ITEM_FIXUTRES = [
  'Item 1',
  'Item 2'
];

App.ITEM_FIXTURES = App.ITEM_FIXUTRES.map(function (item) {
  return Ember.Object.create({title: item});
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.ITEM_FIXTURES;
  },

  actions: {
    add: function(title) {
      var items = this.modelFor('index');
      items.addObject(Ember.Object.create({title: title}));

      this.controller.set('title', '');
    },
    removeAll: function() {
      var items = this.modelFor('index');

      items.forEach(function (item) {
        // I actually only want to remove certain objects with specific
        // properties but this illustrates the issue.
        items.removeObject(item);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The template is fairly straightforward:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <h4>Collection List</h4>

  <button {{action 'removeAll'}}>Remove All</button>

  <ul>
    {{#each}}
      <li>{{title}}</li>
    {{/each}}

    <li>{{input type='text' value=title action='add'}}</li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

Here is a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/kelinime/4/edit

Comment: If I had to take a guess, removeObject is mutating items as you iterate through it.  Each iteration is changing the object, yet it's still attempting to iterate through the original object.  Maybe instead negate the condition and build a new list - instead of `if (cond) remove;` use `if (!cond) newList.push(item) ; items = newList; // or something similar`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Snappie above is correct, you shouldn't modify a collection you're iterating.  You would create a copy of the collection, then iterate that.

```
removeAll: function() {
  var items = this.modelFor('index'),
      list = items.toArray();

  list.forEach(function (item) {
    // I actually only want to remove certain objects with specific
    // properties but this illustrates the issue.
    items.removeObject(item);
  });
}
```

http://jsbin.com/kelinime/7/edit

I realize you say you aren't trying to delete all, but you can also call `removeObjects` with a list of objects and let Ember handle the iterating.  Additionally if the case comes up, you can remove by index also, by using `removeAt`.

```
removeAll: function() {
  var items = this.modelFor('index'),
      list = items.toArray();
  items.removeObjects(list);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/kelinime/8/edit

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it acceptable to modify or set properties of items in a collection I'm iterating?

Comment: definitely, it's just ill advised to modify the collection itself.  The items in the collection are free game

Comment: Nice answer. `filter` creates a new array so I find passing the result of that to `removeObjects` works well.